# Wiring up a computer fan to a normal outlet, without using a computer PSU

Tags: power-supply, transformer, fan

Ive got a Rack that is getting abit hot and i would like to cool using fans. Ive checked out units made by Mid Atlantic c.£300 which are really expensive, but have also come across places selling fan rack mounting panels for normal pc fans for about £10 and can hold 3 fans, and then a normal pc fan is about £6 each so i thought id give that a try first.

My question is how to power them up, as i understand a pc fan has a molex connection on it, as its meant to be used with a computer PSU, but in this application is there a way i could wire this so that it would work with a vis some sort of transformer ?

Power supply wise im in the UK.

Comment: Do you have a 12V supply in your rack? If so you can just connect the fans directly to it.

Answer (score 1):

Any 12V power supply of suitable amperage would work. Of course you will need to cut and splice the wires to connect them. A spare psu works great as well,  often just needing a jumper wire and maybe a power resistor on the five volt rail.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find fans similar to "Computer fans" designed for 120 or 240 volt AC operation.  They can be connected directly to the AC power source.